# Testing javascript alerts with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm writing some Jasmine tests for some legacy javascript that produces an alert or a confirm at some points in the code.

At the moment where the alert pops up it pauses execution in the browser requiring me to press ok before going on.

I'm sure I'm missing something but is there a way of faking an alert?

Even better is it possible to find out what the message was for the alert?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See this link                    https://gist.github.com/roine/9621298

Comment: You should change the accepted answer here to jolySoft's.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
spyOn(window, 'alert');
. . . 
expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a message');
```

Comment: How about window.confirm with ability to confirm or dismiss?

Comment: remember `spyOn(window, 'alert');` as soon as possible, it will not work if you call `expect(window.alert)` immediately after spy

Answer (score 4):

```
var oldalert = alert;
alert = jasmine.createSpy();
// do something
expect(alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('message')
alert = oldalert
```

Comment: This works as well, only problem with it is that it doesn't stop the native alert function being called in Chrome, which could get annoying if you have to run lots of tests.

Comment: using the following will overwrite the native alert function for my purposes.
    window.alert = jasmine.createSpy().andCallFake(function (message) {
    console.log("fake Alert");
    });`

Comment: This is a correct way to always get the last alert message

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to do this in spec helper.

```
window.alert = function(){return;};
```

Or if you need the message.

```
var actualMessage = ''; 
window.alert = function(message){actualMessage = message; return;}
```

Comment: He/She wants to know `what the message was for the alert?`. so this solution is not really helping but to suppress the alert dialog.

Comment: This IS the solution! You want the alert to get out of the testing... and all other solutions still make you click, when running the test. This one, not.

Comment: If you want to know the message sent in the alert use a variable and set it like this.

var actualMessage;
window.alert = function(message){actualMessage = message; return;}

Answer (score 0):

You simply create a spy, surprisingly with `createSpy()`, to mock the function that contains the alert. So you can do something like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    functionWithAlert = jasmine.createSpy("functionWithAlert");    
    functionWithAlert("called as usual");
});
```

You can also do this to return something

```
oldFunctionWithAlert = jasmine.createSpy("oldFunctionWithAlert() spy").andCallFake(function() {
    console.log("Doing some testing");
    return "Test";
});
```

On a side note, I would suggest you replace the alert if possible with less disruptive alternatives. There are a ton of options out there like [JQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).